# Decrypting a known string

Tags: string, encryption

I'm wondering if it is possible to decrypt a string - I know the original, pre-encrypted string value. I'm attempting to audit the strength of a custom made procedure which generates tokens.

Any guidance in the right direction is appreciated - Thanks!

Comment: The question is too vague. Add some detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is depend on using cryprtographic algorithm. For example if you use `MD5` you may try generating hash colision. But it is very hard in pratice. Next, very know method working with some algorithm is plain text attack. Very common method cracking hash is `rainbow tables` and GPU procesor. But when you use hasing algorithm you may very simple improve secruity, using salt. Even RSA is't full resistant to cracking, aproximately 99,98% key is god. Rest is bad, it is caused using weakness in `PRNG`. You may read about this in PDF:
http://eprint.iacr.org/2012/064.pdf

Comment: Do you know of any tools which I can use with a crib to decrypt the string? Let's assume it's MD5.

Answer (score 1):

You say: "I'm attempting to audit the strength of a custom made procedure which generates tokens."  Unless it was "custom made" by a very expensive security consultant then it will be insecure.  In security it is vital to get every tiny detail correct, and anyone without years of training in security won't be able to do that.

There are already plenty of well understood cryptographic methods for many purposes, almost certainly including yours.  Find them and use them.  A "custom made" procedure will contain errors.  Guaranteed.

See [WEP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wired_Equivalent_Privacy#Flaws) for a story of getting the tiny details wrong.

Comment: I'm not arguing that the custom made procedure is strong. I was looking for a tool, which could make breaking its integrity quick. I completely agree with you, but some customers think they're Vincent Rijmen. I ended up breaking this with a rainbow table as a proof of concept.. Thank you for the reply!